# Android APK using external data

Tags: android, android-external-storage

Hi i am looking into an android development , as we all know when we build the project it makes an APK that is the whole program. but is it possible to make a an android project / APK that would be able to use external files to include more info into the project.

like say for example i have a list commands or functions in my list , but i dont want it to be added into my APK build , is it possible to use it externally?

i was curious because something like COC and other games after downloading it , then downloads extra data from the net , more into updates for the whole game.

how is this possible or is it possible to do , and use functions or source codes externally and not include it into the APK , and also the proper usage of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Android App can connect to the Internet and save downloaded data files to use as they need, without requiring to include them inside the APK. Indeed, for many games (and other Apps having large data sets), it's a sensible option.

There are a couple of things to be aware of:

- Android restricts where (on the filesystem) you can save files. And no matter where you save the files, the user can delete them at any
  time. Your App should be able to cope with this.
- The files should only ever be *data* files - not executable code. Attempting to
  execute downloaded files is likely to put your users at risk
  (depending on the permissions your App was installed with) and is also likely to get your App marked as malware.

You should read the Android documentation on [Data Storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to learn a bit more about it.